# Цифры в эмуляторе WP7 при отладке

Tags: отладка, windows-phone-7

что это за цифры? и как ими управлять?
[image]
если запускать без отладки то они не появляются

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Отладочная информация, кол-во FPS, занимаемой памяти и т.д., подробнее в [блоге Сергея Пугачёва](http://pugachev.info/archives/471)